# Ubuntu screen brightness issue only at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, laptop, brightness

Ubuntu 14.04 / Windows 10 dual boot

The laptop can´t remember brightness before, but after manually set the brightness in the rc.local file, it can now remember the brightness level after boot into the system. Recently I recovered the grub boot loader after reinstalled Windows. And the strange thing happened, every time when the computer restarts, from the displaying of the laptop logo to the displaying of the Ubuntu logo it will be at maximum brightness, but after booting into the desktop, it will be again return to normal brightness. This also happens with booting into Windows. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

adding a line into /etc/rc.local will work.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following to the file, x symbolizes the desired brightness level.

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This should solve issue related with ubuntu, i have no idea about windows, you can try to check superuser for windows solution.